# Get only one row if is not equals

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have my table:

```
ID | NAME | TYPE             
1  | A    | 1    
2  | A    | NULL  
3  | B    | NULL  
4  | C    | 2    
5  | D    | NULL 
6  | D    | NULL
```

and i want to for example if i choose Type 1 i get the row but i want all the null values from the other.

```
ID | NAME | TYPE             
1  | A    | 1    
3  | B    | NULL  
5  | D    | NULL 
6  | D    | NULL
```

sometime like this. i try with union but i get repeat **A    | NULL**

thx for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where type = 1
union all
select t.*
from t
where type is null and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.type = 1);
```

You don't actually need the `union all`:

```
select t.*
from t
where type = 1 or
      (type is null and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.type = 1)
      );
```